# Set the 'this' value in ajax callback

Tags: jquery, ajax, coffeescript

I built a jquery function that takes options and makes an ajax PUT request. But I'm having trouble customizing the success callback because this gets redefined. Does anyone know how to keep the value of 'this'?

**jquery function**

```
 (($) ->
    $.textToInputUpdate = (options) ->
      functionality =
        options: $.extend({
          'id_for_put': ""
          'post_url': ""
          'size': 10
        }, options)
        initialize: (event, target) ->
          # ...
          self = this
          field.focusout (event) ->
            $.ajax
              url: self.options.post_url
              type: 'PUT'
              dataType: "json"
              data:
                rubric_item:
                  weight: parseFloat(field.val().trim())
              success: (data) ->
                self.options.success_callback?(data)

      return functionality
  ) jQuery
```

**Calling jquery function with options**

```
  $('#rubric').on 'click', '.rubric-item .rubric-value', (e) ->
    $.textToInputUpdate(
      id_for_put: $(this).parent().attr('id')
      post_url: $(this).parent().data("post-url")
      size: 3
      success_callback: (data) ->
        # PROBLEM HERE: $(this) gets redefined when actually called in the function above. I want it to be the value of $(.rubric-value).
        $(this).text(data.description)
    )
    .initialize(e, $(this))
```

Comment: `self` seems to work, doesn't it?

Comment: @Bergi Sure, but if you can get the bindings correct, it makes it easier to seperate functions into named ones on equal tabbing levels, if/when a series of callbacks gets bloated. So it's still good to know even if you're lazy and use `self`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just use a [fat arrow](http://coffeescript.org/#fat-arrow):

```
$.textToInputUpdate(
  id_for_put: $(this).parent().attr('id')
  post_url: $(this).parent().data("post-url")
  size: 3
  success_callback: (data) =>
#                          ^^
    $(this).text(data.description)
)
```

Much more idiomatic coffeescript than `self` or `that` variables.

Comment: I didn't know that fat arrow was available in coffeescript. This is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

You should assign `this` to a different variable to be used later:

```
$('#rubric').on 'click', '.rubric-item .rubric-value', (e) ->
  var that = this;
  $.textToInputUpdate(
    id_for_put: $(this).parent().attr('id')
    post_url: $(this).parent().data("post-url")
    size: 3
    success_callback: (data) ->
      $(that).text(data.description)
  ).initialize(e, $(this))
```

Comment: Why does `this` change? I have a similar issue where I am using `this` in my complete callback, and inside the the callback it changes from a Node to an object.